# ruby-style conditional setting of python variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Ruby, if you want to set the value of a variable conditionally, you can do something like this:

```
foo = myhash[ "bar" ] || myhash[ "baz" ]
```

And it will set the value of foo to myhash[ "bar" ] if it exists, otherwise it will set foo to myhash[ "baz" ]. If neither exist, it will set foo to nil.

In Python, you will get a syntax error if you try this type of assignment. Moreover, Python will throw a KeyError on myhash[ "baz" ] instead of setting it to None. It seems to me that the only way to conditionally set foo in Python is to write a big multi-line conditional statement, but I would really love to just do this in one line like Ruby. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a syntax error because the syntax for the python [or operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) is different, and you need to explicitly ask Python to return `None` from a dictionary lookup using the [`.get()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
foo = myhash.get('bar') or myhash.get('baz')
```

Because `.get()` takes a default value to return instead of the looked-for key (which defaults to `None`, you can also spell this as:

```
foo = myhash.get('bar', myhash.get('baz'))
```

This has the added benefit that if `myhash['bar']` is false-y (evaluates to False in a boolean context, such as empty sequences or numerical 0) it'll still return `myhash['bar']` and not `myhash['baz']`.

Comment: Note that the first fails for falsy values of `myhash['bar']`, such as zero or empty strings. The Ruby version acts differently (only false and nil are falsy), which is why they get away with it.

Comment: @delnan: right, and that's why the second spelling is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = myhash.get('bar', myhash['baz'])
```

This does raise an error if the 'baz' key is not present, but I'd consider that a bug anyway and wouldn't want the language to silent it. If the second item is also optional and you want `None` as final fallback, you can also use `.get` for the second lookup.